# 2 problems about recursive DFS

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search

```
/*
Problem 22 Generate Parentheses:
Given n pairs of parentheses, write a function to generate all combinations of well-formed parentheses.For example, given n = 3, a solution set is: "((()))", "(()())", "(())()", "()(())", "()()()"
 */

public List<String> generateParenthesis(int n) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    backtrack(list, "", 0, 0, n);
    return list;
}

private void backtrack(List<String> list, String str, int open, int close, int max){

    if(str.length() == max*2){
        list.add(str);
        return;
    }
    if(open < max)
        backtrack(list, str + "(", open + 1, close, max);
    if(close < open)
        backtrack(list, str+")", open, close+1, max);
}
```

This is one popular solution on LeetCode, I know DFS theory, I just cannot get it for two points.

1. In recursive function, there's two options after add a '(', either add another '(' or add some ')', but code is executed from up to down, how can these code process other solutions except ((())).
   Like (()()), how does it add a ')' after two '('
2. After finished one solution, add it to list and return, how does it get other solutions after return? Doesn't it mean this method will end after return?
   New learner about Java, thanks for detailed answers

Answer (score 0):

I inserted this line at the top of your `backtrack()` method:

```
System.out.println("backtrack(" + list + ", \"" + str + "\", " + 
                   open + ", " + close + ", " + max + ")");
```

Here is what it generates for n = 3. I think this would help you see how recursion is working here.

```
backtrack([], "", 0, 0, 3)
-backtrack([], "(", 1, 0, 3)
--backtrack([], "((", 2, 0, 3)
---backtrack([], "(((", 3, 0, 3)
----backtrack([], "((()", 3, 1, 3)
-----backtrack([], "((())", 3, 2, 3)
------backtrack([], "((()))", 3, 3, 3)
---backtrack([((()))], "(()", 2, 1, 3)
----backtrack([((()))], "(()(", 3, 1, 3)
-----backtrack([((()))], "(()()", 3, 2, 3)
------backtrack([((()))], "(()())", 3, 3, 3)
----backtrack([((())), (()())], "(())", 2, 2, 3)
-----backtrack([((())), (()())], "(())(", 3, 2, 3)
------backtrack([((())), (()())], "(())()", 3, 3, 3)
--backtrack([((())), (()()), (())()], "()", 1, 1, 3)
---backtrack([((())), (()()), (())()], "()(", 2, 1, 3)
----backtrack([((())), (()()), (())()], "()((", 3, 1, 3)
-----backtrack([((())), (()()), (())()], "()(()", 3, 2, 3)
------backtrack([((())), (()()), (())()], "()(())", 3, 3, 3)
----backtrack([((())), (()()), (())(), ()(())], "()()", 2, 2, 3)
-----backtrack([((())), (()()), (())(), ()(())], "()()(", 3, 2, 3)
------backtrack([((())), (()()), (())(), ()(())], "()()()", 3, 3, 3)
```

Dashes represent the depth of stack when each recursive call is made (I achieved this effect by adding an additional `String` parameter to `backtrack` that is initialized by "" in `generateParenthesis` and is concatenated by a "-" each time recursion happens).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit confused about the location of the return and also about the if statement inside your recursive function, backtrack.

Recursive functions go deeper and deeper until they arrive at a case called base case from which they can not descend any further. You should note that each level of descending is achieved by a call to your recursive function. The crucial point is that **each call to it is a call to a separate function and hence should return separately**.

If what you intuitively, and sadly incorrectly though was correct, then upon reaching base case you would just terminate recursion entirely. Instead, if you have a recurrence relation as below and you make a call such as f(n) from a function g, your recurrence will down like f(n-1), f(n-2),...f(2), f(1), f(0). When f(0) returns, it will not return its value to g. It will in fact return its value again to the function f, argument for which was 1. (i.e. basically following the direction it used while descending to f(0), only in reverse) f(1) will, then, return to the function f, argument for which was 2. This will continue until you reach invocation of f argument for which was n. Only then, the return value will be returned to g.

```
private void f(int i){
    if(i == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return f(i-1); 
    }
}
```

The first question you have in mind is I think quite easier to respond if you get what I have mentioned above. What I mentioned above was, in a nutshell, a call to a lower level of recursion does not entail that once that call to a lower level returns, the current level of recursion will be terminated as well. If you understand that fact, in order to answer your first question, all you need to do is to notice that the branching in backtrack function is conducted using two **if** functions and not a single if&else-if function. In essence once the first(i.e. one with '(' as an argument) backtrack call to the lower level of recursion returns, as the current level of recursion will not terminate, a separate if check will be run, and if found necessary (i.e. close < open) backtrack will be called for the second time. (i.e. this time with ')' and other relevant arguments) As this is done at each level of recursion, this function can add ')' after adding '(' 2 times.